# Could not find xcb while launching Qt applications

Tags: linux-mint, qt

I am currently using Linux Mint 18.1 with Cinnamon 3.4 installed. I am using the Linux Kernel 4.10.0-21-generic.

I have been recently having problems with Qt. I installed Qt to build some programs from their source, but I don't have to do that anymore. I went ahead and did a stupid thing, and that was uninstalling Qt manually. I deleted the directory in which I installed it to (`/home/nicholas/.Qt`) and removed the menu items.

However, now I am experiencing an issue. Certain applications such as CopyQ do not function at all. Running them in the commandline brings up this:

```
ERROR: QtFatal: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
ERROR:    
ERROR:    Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. (:0, )
terminate called after throwing an instance of '(anonymous namespace)::ExceptionQtFatal'
  what():  This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. (:0, )
Aborted
```

This is from CopyQ. There is another few applications that run into this problem but I cannot remember them off the top of my head.

I have tried reinstalling Qt in the same and in different directories many times, even uninstalling using the maintenance tool in the Qt. Looking it up many times with different keywords didn't yield any results that I was looking for. No solution has helped at all.

I have tried using the offline installer and installing it in the same directory, `/home/nicholas/.Qt` and it didn't work. I am installing only the latest version of Qt which is 5.9.0 from what I can tell.